# SqlAlchemy difference of timestamps

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a table to log user actions. I dont have different columns for different action types yet for my newest task, I have to find the average time difference inbetween some actions.

```html
class UserAction(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user_action"
    id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id))
    case_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('case.id'))
    category_id = Column(Integer)
    action_time = Column(DateTime(), server_default=func.now())
```

So I want to do something like,

```html
x = session.query(func.avg(UserAction.action_time)).filter(UserAction.category_id == 1).all()

y = session.query(func.avg(UserAction.action_time)).filter(UserAction.category_id == 2).all()
dif = x - y
```

or

```html
session.query(func.avg(func.justify_hours(timestamp_column1) - func.justify_hours(timestamp_column1))).all()
```

I can create a new table to log each case's actions' in different columns to do it like thw first way but that wont be efficient. But if i do it like the second way, the output won't be correct becasue not all actions are done by all cases. So im a little bit stuck. How can i achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: your problem is rather how to organize data in database, not how to calculate diff timestamps.